# Injecting resolve into directive with dynamic controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have a directive with dynamic controller which is passed via controller-name property.

**Directive:**

```
angular
        .module('directives.panel', [])
        .directive('panel', panel);

panel.$inject = ['$timeout', '$parse'];

        function panel($timeout, $parse) {

            var directive = {
                restrict: 'EA',
                transclude: true,
                replace: true,
                template: '<div class="panel panel-solid panel-table" ng-transclude></div>',
                controller: '@',
                name: 'controllerName',
                controllerAs: 'panel',
                link: linkFunc
            };

            return directive;

            }
        }
```

Is it possible to inject resolve 'taskbook' object into dynamic controller?
When I try to do that I get unknown provider. However injecting Resource service (GroupResource) works fine.

Is it possible to inject resolve in directive controller?

**State**

```
angular
        .module('taskbooks.taskbook', [
            'deployment.group',
            'resource.deployment',
            'resource.taskbook'
        ])
        .config(TaskbookConfig)
        .controller('TaskbookController', TaskbookController);

    TaskbookConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$provide'];

    function TaskbookConfig($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('taskbooks.taskbook', {
                url: 'taskbooks/:taskbookId',
                parent: 'taskbooks',
                views: {
                    "mainContent@taskbooks": {
                        controller: 'TaskbookController as taskbook',
                        templateUrl: 'taskbook/taskbook.tpl.html'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    taskbook: TaskbookPrepare
                }
            });
    }

    TaskbookPrepare.$inject = ['$stateParams', 'TaskbookResource'];

    function TaskbookPrepare($stateParams, TaskbookResource) {

        return TaskbookResource.get({
            taskbookId: $stateParams.taskbookId
        }).$promise;
    }
```

**Directive Controller**

```
angular
       .module('deployment.groups', ['resource.group'])
       .controller('DeploymentGroupController',DeploymentGroupController);

      DeploymentGroupController.$inject = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', 'GroupResource', 'taskbook']; 
      function DeploymentGroupController($scope, $element, $attrs, GroupResource, taskbook)  {

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of... If this directive requires the resolve that is associated with this state, then it's safe to assume it will only ever be used in this state, correct?

Going on that idea, the directive can reference the controller set in the state and you can add the resolve to the controller scope.

Here's a very simplified version of what I'm saying...

```
angular
    .module('taskbooks.taskbook')
    .config([ $stateProvider, function ($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('taskbook', {
                url: '/:id',
                parent: 'taskbooks',
                resolve: {
                    taskbook: [ '$stateParams', 'TaskbookResource', function ($stateParams, TaskbookResource) {
                        return TaskbookResource.get({
                            taskbookId: $stateParams.taskbookId
                        }).$promise;
                    }]
                },
                controller: ['taskbook', function (taskbook) {
                    this.taskbook = taskbook;
                }],
                controllerAs: 'taskController'
            });

    }])
    .directive('someDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EAC',
            controller: 'taskController',
            link: function (scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
                var taskbook = ctrl.taskbook;
            }
        }
    });
```

Do note, I removed a lot of the non-relevant code from yours just to get the point across quicker. Obviously this can be reworked into the structure you've written.